# Mysql - index - optimization (two separate or a multikey)

Tags: mysql, index

I have a question for the experts I couldn't find an easy answer in the docs:
I'm using pseudo code as the real table doesn't matter so much on the theoretical question itself.

Given I have a table with 500 million rows.

```
id, dt_date, string, int_type
```

I have two sort of queries:

```
a) select * from table WHERE (date > x and id = y) FOR update
b) select * from table WHERE (date > x and id = y and type = z)
```

Should I create two indexes, one per query:

```
date,id and date,id,type
```

Or one index to serve both queries:

```
date,id,type
```

Two indexes will take quite a bit of extra storage space given that it's half a billion rows.
One index would be my favorite solution if both queries are expected to run with the same performance.

Comment: Move fields which are checked by direct value to the front of the index. So create indices by `(id, date)` and `(id, type, date)`. If `type` field is more selective than `id` one, create `(type, id, date)` instead of second index shown above. And think carefully - do you really need in ALL fields from the table? if not, maybe covering index will be more effective...

Comment: [How mysql uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). [query optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization)

Comment: `(id, type, date)` and `(type, id, date)` have the same cardinality, and their BTrees have the same depth.  So there is no difference in performance.  OTOH, `(type)` and `(id)` _do_ vary in cardinality and perhaps depth, and hence performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(id)` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then no secondary indexes are needed.  (Hint:  I would really help to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  A `PRIMARY KEY` has a uniqueness constraint.  That is, there can be only one or zero rows satisfied by those `SELECTs`.

Is the table InnoDB?  (See hint above)

In any case, do not start an index with a range (eg, `date > x`), the Optimizer cannot get past it to look at the rest of the columns.

In InnoDB, you really need to specify a PK.

OK, I'll assume `id` is not the PK.  Then you need

```
INDEX(id, date)
INDEX(id, type,   -- in either order
      date)
```

No single index handles both queries equally well.  However, I would compromise on only `(id, date)` to avoid an extra huge index.

(An aside..) If `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `INT` (see hint above), check the max value.  With 500M rows, you might be getting close to the 2 billion limit.  If `INT UNSIGNED` the limit is about 4 billion.

Are you really doing `*` (in `SELECT *`)?  Knowing the actual list may lead to developing a "covering" index.

Use InnoDB and have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Based on your Comments)

If `(id, date)` is unique, then make that the PK. and toss the other index.

If `(id, type, date)` is unique, make it the PK and toss the other index.

Now, you have gotten rid of both secondary indexes, *and* you have made one of the queries quite efficient due to its index being "clustered".  Meanwhile, the other index is not too bad off because there won't be more than "a few thousand" rows, and the clustered PK is still helpful.

If you have at least 8GB of RAM and `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G`, the table will possibly stay in cache.  Even if not, the "clustering" will make the queries work efficiently even if the cache is much smaller than the table.

Comment: Thanks.
It's not an autoincrement. I didn't know that I should use the id first. I used the date first so far.

I am using this for selects, GROUPs and SELECT FOR UPDATE to later update the rows found

Comment: @John - Please provide specifics so I won't be hurting those queries while helping the two you showed here.  That `id` points into some other table?  And it repeats a lot in this `table`?  You have `GROUP BY` somewhere?  Etc.

Comment: the ID mentioned is not the primary id.
It does point to another table but is no foreign key.
It's the primary key of another table, it's repeating possibly a few thousand times but in most cases not more than a few times.

One query does a WHERE date > now() - interval 1 hour GROUP BY id
I think that won't be an issue, the amount within the WHERE is not more than a few ten thousand max and I have a separate index for that query

Comment: For `WHERE date > now() - interval 1 hour GROUP BY id`, the optimal index is a 'composite' `INDEX(id, date)`, same as for your query "a".

Comment: I added stuff on the PK.